# ROSBAG on Windows/WinROS

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosbag, winros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,
I recently used RGBD Slam for my project from my Ubuntu Machine and it did work great. Really Cool Stuff.
However i have both the Kinect for XBox and Kinect for Windows. I want to use the Kinect for Windows as it has a Near Mode capability and i believe the Maps could be better with it. So i plan to install WinRos and run ROSBAG from it and bag all the required files and then transfer the files to Linux and run it alongside RGBDSLAM.
Is this Possible??

If its possible could somebody guide me some steps on how to use WinRos and ROSBAG on it. I don't see proper documentation for it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61336/rosbag-on-windows/winros/) by [preetham.hegde](https://answers.ros.org/users/4262/preetham.hegde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-04-28**:
Unrelated to your problem, but a hint for when you solved it: Instead of playing the bagfile with rosbag and let rgbdslam run meanwhile, you can set the "bagfile_name" parameter, to let rgbdslam process every frame (or every nth frame with "data_skip_set" set to n), regardless of the processing time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Myself and another contributor got the recording parts of rosbag patched in fuerte. If you go with the groovy [winros instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/win_ros/groovy/Msvc%20Compiled%20SDK), then you should find yourself with a runnable rosbag environment (works the same way as a linux rosbag environment).

If you decide to try, join us on the [winros mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/win-ros), I'd be happy to field questions and hear how it goes from there.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [preetham.hegde](https://answers.ros.org/users/4262/preetham.hegde/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thanks @Daniel Stonier. I will try it out and get back with an answer as soon as possible.